# Matplotlib legend half-color line entry

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way of drawing a multi-colored line for a single legend entry in Matplotlib?

For example, in the below figure, the line for entries Class 1 and two appear black to the left and gray to the right of the middle point.

[image: example]

Comment: Simply don't draw the label for the other colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the handlers of each label via the tuple legend handler ([`HandlerTuple`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple)).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.random.rand(2), color='black', ls='--', label='Class 1')
ax.plot(np.random.rand(2), color='.7', ls='--', label='Class 1')
ax.plot(np.random.rand(2), color='black', ls='-', label='Class 2')
ax.plot(np.random.rand(2), color='.7', ls='-', label='Class 2')

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
unique_labels = list(np.unique(labels))
combined_handles = [tuple([h for h, l in zip(handles, labels) if l == label]) for label in unique_labels]

ax.legend(handles=combined_handles, labels=unique_labels, handlelength=3,
          handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None, pad=0)})
plt.show()
```

[image: combining legend with HandlerTuple]

PS: If you have two subplots, you can combine the handles and the labels of both:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
import numpy as np

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(np.random.rand(2), color='black', ls='--', label='Class 1')
ax1.plot(np.random.rand(2), color='black', ls='-', label='Class 2')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(np.random.rand(2), color='.7', ls='--', label='Class 1')
ax2.plot(np.random.rand(2), color='.7', ls='-', label='Class 2')

handles1, labels1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
labels = labels1 + labels2
unique_labels = list(np.unique(labels))
combined_handles = [tuple([h for h, l in zip(handles1 + handles2, labels) if l == label]) for label in unique_labels]

ax1.legend(handles=combined_handles, labels=unique_labels, handlelength=3,
           handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None, pad=0)})
plt.show()
```

[image: combining legends of two axes]

Comment: My data is drawn on two axes, so I solved it by defining the two variables as: `combined_handles=[ ( Line2D(...color='black', ls='--'...), Line2D(...color='black', ls='--'...) ), ( Line2D(...color='black', ls='-'...), Line2D(...color='black', ls='-'...) ) ]` and `unique_labels = ['class 1', 'class 2']`

Comment: Well, there are very good reasons StackOverflow strongly insists on reproducible code examples.  In your case, probably combining the handles and the labels of both axes would work better.  Creating dummy handles has the drawback that they also would need to change when you change something in the original plots.